# Duplicate answers?

Tags: discussion, support, duplicate-answers

Observe the following scenario: You post an answer to a question, and then remember that there is another method to solve the problem. You edit your answer, but after a few minutes someone else post the same method that you added last. What to do? Is there a "Duplicate" flag for answers?

*Note: I am pretty sure that the user did not use the same method on purpose, just because he did not see that I edited my answer.*

Comment: What is the feature request here?

Comment: Don't edit the answer to include another separate answer. If you have a different answer, write a different answer, so they can both be curated and voted on their own merit, not with massively mixed signals.

Comment: Possibly related: [Add an option to leave a "This is a duplicate answer" comment when voting to delete an answer from review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371341/add-an-option-to-leave-a-this-is-a-duplicate-answer-comment-when-voting-to-del)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why do anything at all? If you both answered the question at the same time independently and your answers are similar, just leave them be.

The only thing to note is that if you both answered quite quickly and your answers are similar that may suggest that the question itself is a duplicate because it may well be about some well known and simple concept that already has a suitable Q&A.